# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Chapter 9, Exercise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Obviously a novice here, but working through Hartl's book.  I can't seem to figure out how to write the right tests for Exercise 3: "The current authentication tests check that navigation links such as “Profile” and “Settings” appear when a user is signed in. Add tests to make sure that these links don’t appear when a user isn’t signed in.":

Here's my authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do

subject { page }

  describe "signin path" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',     text: "Sign in") }
    it { should have_selector('title',  text: "Sign in") }
  end

  describe "should not have show profile and settings in menu" do

    it { should_not have_link('Profile',        href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should_not have_link('Settings',   href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid signin information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: "Invalid") }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }

        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid signin information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user } 

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

      it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',     href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',     href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in',  href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end

    describe "authorization" do

      describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
          before do
            visit edit_user_path(user)
            fill_in "Email",        with: user.email
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
          end

          describe "after signing in" do
            it "should render the desired protected page" do
              page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
            end
          end
        end

        describe "in the Users controller" do

          describe "visiting the edit page" do
            before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
            it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
          end

          describe "submitting to the update action" do
            before { put user_path(user) }
            specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
          end

          describe "visiting the user index" do
            before { visit users_path }
            it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign in") }
          end
        end
      end

      describe "as wrong user" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
        before { sign_in user }

        describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
          it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
        end

        describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
          before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
        end
      end

      describe "as a non-admin user" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        before { sign_in non_admin }

        describe "submitting a DELETE request to the User#destroy action" do
          before { delete user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
        end
      end
   end
 end
end
```

The lines I added have the tests still failing.  Any insight would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something but I can't see which tests you have added for this exercise.

I have just completed this and now the first AuthenticationPages tests look like this.

**authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
describe "sigin page" do
  before { visit signin_path }

  it { should have_content('Sign in') }
  it { should have_title('Sign in') }

  it { should_not have_link('Users') }
  it { should_not have_link('Profile') }
  it { should_not have_link('Settings') }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  it { should have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end
```

Comment: I believe I had too many lines under one of my test sections.

Answer (score 0):

In addition KnownColor's tests above, I added the following tests to verify that the links do not show on profile pages when the user is not signed in:

**authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
describe "authorization" do

  describe "for non-signed-in users" do

    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    describe "when visiting a non-protected page" do
      before {visit user_path(user)}
      it {should have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path)}
      it {should_not have_link('Users')}
      it {should_not have_link('Profile')}
      it {should_not have_link('Settings')}
      it {should_not have_link('Sign out')}
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```